# Munit maven error

Tags: maven, munit

I am getting an error while trying to run Munit using Maven. It's a domain project and my Munit test cases are available in mule projects. when I ran maven, it is giving me file not found exception (mule-domain-config.xml). I tried all possible ways by checking in this site but of no luck. Below is the stack trace.

> INFO 2017-01-06 01:15:01,226 [main]
>   org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager: Loading mule-app.properties
>   ... INFO 2017-01-06 01:15:01,319 [main]
>   org.mule.munit.runner.domain.MunitDomainContextBuilder: Loading
>   mule-deploy.properties ... java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: mule-domain-config.xml
>   (java.io.FileNotFoundException)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check for the pom.xml file for proper configurations.

If you are still facing the issue try cleaning anypoint and run it again.It might Work.